# UILocalNotification changes Its ApplicationIconBadgeNumber Dynamically When Not Showing Previous Notification in iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying for few days to do an alarm App which will sent a Localnotification everyDay at 8AM.
my code is below working nicely in foreground, background and Suspended states.

```
NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date]
                     dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
self.notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                    init];
//   if (notifyAlarm){
self.notifyAlarm.fireDate = alertTime;
self.notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
self.notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
//    notifyAlarm.soundName = @"bell_tree.mp3";
self.notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Staff meeting in 30 minutes";
self.notifyAlarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber=[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
[app scheduleLocalNotification:self.notifyAlarm];
//   }
```

But I need to Increase the Badge number when I didnt seen previous local Notification that has been fired.
and Decrease Automatically When I see that Notification Dynamically.

Please anyone Help me

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible in local push notification: 
Please refer the following link: DUPLICATE ASKED QUESTION AS OF YOU.**

[How to increment application badge number for recurring local notification (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251081/how-to-increment-application-badge-number-for-recurring-local-notification-ipho)