# Schedule daily update of IconBadgeNumber from applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification, badge

I've been able to **set an application badge number** to my iPhone app and updating it once the user interacts with my app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication ] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:currNrOfNotif];
```

*What I wont though*, is for this process to **occur while in background mode**, ie from within `applicationDidEnterBackground` or similar. I would like this process to be **scheduled to run daily, every night at 00:00 00:00** and take the current number in setApplicationIconBadgeNumber and **decrement it by -1**. No need for push notifications (or any server kind) in other words as the only thing that will happen is a change of the badge number value.

First of all, **how do I schedule an activity to occur while app's in background mode**, without using remote server push notifications?

Secondly, **how do I get or fetch the current application notification badge value and decrement it by one**?

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962054/iphone-incrementing-the-application-badge-through-a-local-notification), some people argue it simply can't be done even with local notifications and that server side push's required. One person, however, **states it can be done** by scheduling it by midnight. Who's right, and can someone please propose a solution to this?

Comment: The answer on that question that suggested this was possible in the way you describe is incorrect. The other two answers are pretty much your only option here.

Comment: are you sure, think I've seen it being described elsewhere too?

Comment: The only cases in which your application can be running in the background are described in the multitasking programming guide: when it’s providing navigation, background audio, or VoIP, and for ~10 minutes after it goes to the background. None of those are suited to setting up this kind of scheduled task. I’d recommend using the local-notification approach.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I'll go for local notifications then. Could you please provide a sample code of how to do this and I'll gladly up your suggested answer and mark it as the correct one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Incrementing the application badge through a local notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962054/iphone-incrementing-the-application-badge-through-a-local-notification)