# How to increment/decrement application.badge number for UILocalnotification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have UILocalnotification when multiple notification is fired i want application badge number to get increment and when notification is seen i want application badge number to decrease depending upon how many notification is cancelled / watched the notification

```
 - (UILocalNotification *)scheduleNotification :(int)remedyID
{
        NSString *descriptionBody;
        NSInteger frequency;

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];


        descriptionBody =[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];
        frequency = [[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyFrequency"]intValue];

        NSArray *notificationFireDates = [self fireDatesForFrequency:frequency];

        for (NSDate *fireDate in notificationFireDates)
        {
                notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


                notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithString:descriptionBody];
                notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
                notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

                notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

                notif.fireDate = fireDate;


                NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:notif.alertBody,                                         @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey",  [NSNumber numberWithInt:remedyID],kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey,
                                          nil];

                notif.userInfo = userDict;

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
            }

            return notif;

}

}

- (void)cancelNotification:(int)remedyId
{


    NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    NSLog(@"Cancelling... Before %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

    for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications)
    {

        int notifRemedyId = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey"]intValue];

        NSLog(@"remedyID  : %d",remedyId);
        NSLog(@"notifyId : %d",notifRemedyId);
        if (remedyId == notifRemedyId)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }

    }

    NSLog(@"Cancelling... After %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

}
```

Comment: Here's it.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962054/iphone-incrementing-the-application-badge-through-a-local-notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962054/iphone-incrementing-the-application-badge-through-a-local-notification)

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use these two methods,

```
-(void) incrementOneBadge{
    NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    numberOfBadges +=1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];
}

-(void) decrementOneBdge{
    NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    numberOfBadges -=1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];
}
```

Comment: numberOfBadges -=1;   this is used to decrement applicationiconbadgenumber right ?

Comment: should i use this method in my MainViewController or should it be also present in appdelegate

Comment: i'll let u know tomo ...btw when there are multiple notification the badge number will get increment automatically

Comment: you can just set the number depending on your needs, [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:4]; or any number

Comment: if i set 4 ...and say 3 notifications are fired ..does it show 3 applicationbadgenumber ? ..is setApplicationBadgeNumber : 4 means max of 4 will be shown ?

Comment: 4 is exactly 4, [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:4]; must show you 4 badges..

Comment: i want to set setApplicationBadgeNumber  depending upon how many notiification is fired it may be 2,4,15 etc ..`numberOfBadges +=1;`.this should solve it right

Comment: yes, also make sure you reduce the number at the correct time

Comment: ok...just one more thing say out of 4 if i see 1 notification ..`numberOfBadges -=1;` will reduce notification to 3 ?

Comment: its not working .. i put this method in my mainviewcontroller.m and when two notification is fired badge number is showing 1 instead of 2

Comment: do you call this method twice ?

Comment: Where to place these two methods and from where to call the same ?