# local notification badge number not more than one

Tags: swift, notifications, numbers, locale, badge

Within few minutes, I got two different local notifications at the same time.
But the badge number of the app show "1" instead of "2"

my code:

```
var localNotification = UILocalNotification()

localNotification.userInfo = ["UUID": FirstReminderString, ]
localNotification.fireDate = SameDay
localNotification.alertBody = "Reminder !"
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Comment: You might find useful additional information in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962054/iphone-incrementing-the-application-badge-through-a-local-notification).

Comment: okay, that means that before a new notification will register, i have to check how many notifications will be active on the same day and get this count number + 1 for the new one?

how can ich check the number of notifications on a day?

Answer (score 1):

When you are scheduling the notifications, the current badge number is taken (and it is likely 0). Thus, the new badge number will be 1 for all notifications you are scheduling before the badge number increments.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in foreground mode: you can adjust badge number by following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; // increase counter
}
```

This method will not be called if app is in background mode.

So we have to do something in server as follows:

```
func sendLocalNotif(notifCountAlreadySent:Int) {

    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()

    localNotification.userInfo = ["UUID": FirstReminderString, ]
    localNotification.fireDate = SameDay
    localNotification.alertBody = "Reminder !"
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notifCountAlreadySent + 1

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

See if it helps. This function receives a tracking number. That is being used as badge number. You have to just keep track of how many notification already sent.

Comment: thx but i need a solution, which set the badge number of the receive locale notifications at the moment - while is the app in background, too

Comment: @Ghost108 You have wrote : "two different local notifications". Have you access on those 2 local notification senders?

Comment: sry for missunstandnig. two local notifications with different content.
but firedate and time is the same

Comment: @Ghost108 App can not track notification count during background mode. It has to be done from server. You have to just track a number from notification sender code.  Is it clear to you?

Comment: sry, i understand what you mean, but i dont know how i can solve it. can you help me?