# Error: Cannot assign to property: 'badge' is a get-only property

Tags: swift, badge, usernotifications

I've tried to create a badge updater for local notifications using the `UserNotifications.framework`. And here's my code

```
 func badgeUpdate() {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (requests) in

        let number = NSNumber(integerLiteral: +1)

        if requests.count != 0 {

            center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()


            for request in requests {

                request.content.badge = number

                center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in

                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an error line:

```
request.content.badge = number
```

And gives me an error like so:  **Cannot assign to property: 'badge' is a get-only property**

How to fix that? Thanks a lot.

Inspired by this link [iPhone: Incrementing the application badge through a local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962054/iphone-incrementing-the-application-badge-through-a-local-notification)

Comment: Are you trying to do this? `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = number`? That's how you set the app's badge number. You're trying to change the badge number the actual request is sending you, which is read-only.

Comment: Does not work. I want create an auto updater like the iOS Reminders app while my app is inactive state. I mean badges